# Javascript code is executed only if i put a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a calendar widget. When the date is changed from the calendar, a "datechange" event is fired.

```
calendar.dateChangeEvent.subscribe(this.handleDateChangeEvent, this,true);
```

I want to select contents of the input box whenever the date is changed.

```
handleDateChangeEvent:function(input){
    input.select()
}
```

Now, if i put a breakpoint inside handleDateChangeEvent, the input box contents get selected. i.e the code works fine. However, it does not work in the normal flow of script execution. I have tried putting the code in setTimeout but no effect.

Comment: Try creating a minimal, standalone case on jsfiddle or codepen. As it stands, this question is difficult to answer helpfully.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This question is *on-topic* for S.O. because it is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" but unfortunately it is *too broad* because "good answers would be too long for [question and answer] format".  Please don't be discouraged when we close the question.  Please read the [Help Center: Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and try again with a more specific question!